# how to expose functionality from reverseproxy service

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

I've got a reverseproxy service, and I'm using [SharpReverseProxy](https://github.com/SharpTools/SharpReverseProxy) to handle all incoming requests:

In order to configure the service, the following code is in the `Startup` class:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
    IHostingEnvironment env, 
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {

    app.UseProxy(new List<ProxyRule> {
        new ProxyRule {
            Matcher = uri => uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("/api/"),
            Modifier = (req, user) => {
                var match = Regex.Match(req.RequestUri.AbsolutePath, "/api/(.+)service");
                req.RequestUri = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}.{1}/{2}",
                    match.Groups[1].Value,
                    req.RequestUri.Host,
                    req.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Replace(match.Value, "/api/")
                ));
            },
            RequiresAuthentication = true
        }
    },
    r => {
        _logger.LogDebug($"Proxy: {r.ProxyStatus} Url: {r.OriginalUri} Time: {r.Elapsed}");
        if (r.ProxyStatus == ProxyStatus.Proxied) {
            _logger.LogDebug($"        New Url: {r.ProxiedUri.AbsoluteUri} Status: {r.HttpStatusCode}");
        }
    });
}
```

How can I expose this service, in such a way where I can externally https to it?

I know that we can add a listener with `FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener` like so:

```
                        new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext => new FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener(serviceContext,
                new MyService(),
                new FabricTransportRemotingListenerSettings
                {
                    EndpointResourceName = "MyServiceEndpoint"
                }), "MyServiceEndpoint"),
```

My problem is, I'm not understanding what should be replaced with `MyService()` because the ReverseProxy code at the top has no services.

**How do I expose the reverseproxy configuration as a service, thereby being able to expose it via `FabricTransportRemotingListenerSettings`?**

Answer (score 2):

You can't. SF remoting is a platform specific communication mechanism. Also, it is not intended to be used from outside the cluster.

You can expose a `HttpSysCommunicationListener` to expose your proxy as an [HTTP endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore#httpsys-in-reliable-services) of a Reliable Service.

Make sure to configure the endpoint as HTTPS as described.